# getUser returns object with name undefined

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I'm using MSAL to log into my B2C Active Directory

The login seems to work ok. I get an ID token, then can use that to get an access token.

If I then use the clientApplication to call getUser, it returns an object but the name is undefined. The user in Azure Active directory has the user.name field filled out

```
    yield login();
    yield put({ type: AUTH_BEGIN_GET_TOKEN });
    const token = yield call(acquireTokenSilent);
    yield put({ type: AUTH_SET_TOKEN, token });
    console.log('getting user');
    const user = ActiveDirectoryClient.clientApplication.getUser();
    console.log('user', user);
```

Comment: Have you added the "Display Name" attribute as an application claim to the Azure AD B2C policy?

Comment: yes it was that. Thanks for the comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had forgotten to tick the display name in the application claim

Answer (score 1):

The "Display Name" attribute is issued as the "name" claim in the Azure AD B2C token so this attribute must be selected in the "Application claims" settings for the Azure AD B2C policy.